# Wifi scanner with 20 scanning purpose

Tags: java, android, class, android-wifi

I was trying to built an array of class and was putting some values to the objects but still it is showing null pointer exception.

my code is :

```
class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
          @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
          public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

              List<ScanResult> wifilist = wifi.getScanResults();
                 info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
                int k = wifilist.size(); 


                scan_data[] data = new scan_data[k];

             for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
                wifi.startScan();
                List<ScanResult> wifilist1 = wifi.getScanResults();

                int l = wifilist1.size();

                if (i==0){
                for (int j=0;j<l;j++){
                    data[j].ssid = wifilist1.get(j).SSID.toString();
                    data[j].bssid = wifilist1.get(j).BSSID.toString();
                    data[j].lvl = wifilist1.get(j).level;
                    data[j].count++;
                }
```

If you could tell me why its is showing null pointer exception at

```
data[j].ssid = wifilist1.get(j).SSID.toString();
```

Comment: Well its just a suggestion that you should debug your code first that what point the condition fails and you get the reason for it.

Comment: your `data` array have `null` at all of its indexes, it has not been initialized till the line where `NPE` occurs.

Comment: @RaviBhatt Thats not correct. list index will be `0` to `l-1` so `j<l` is correct. moreover if that was the problem it would have been an `IndexOutOfBoundException` not `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Sanjeev yes you are correct. good catch.

Comment: @AnkitLamba How do i create a dynamic array. I got your point

Comment: You only have to put value in your array...like `data[0] = new scan_data()` (*You have to do it for all indexes of `data` array*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your scan_Data array is not initialized with objects.

```
scan_data[] data = new scan_data[k];
```

this is just initializing the array not putting objects in it. you have to do it explicitly
So in your for loop. Create scan_data object and put all the values in it and then put that on data[j].

```
         for (int j=0;j<l;j++){
                scan_data sData = new scan_data();
  //            set all desired values in sData from ScanData
                data[j] = sData;
            }
```

Hope this helps.